# rand changes value without changing seed

Tags: c++, random, random-seed

Take the following program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
using std::rand;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    cout << rand() << ' ' << rand() << ' ' << rand() << '\n';
}
```

Due to `rand` producing the same values as long as the seed isn't changed using `srand`, this should produce three identical numbers.
e.g.

```
567 567 567
```

However, when I run this program it gives me three different values.
e.g.

```
6334 18467 41
```

When the program is (compiled and) run again, the same three numbers are generated. Shouldn't I have to use `srand` to change the seed before I start getting different results from `rand`? Is this just my compiler/implementation trying to do me a favour?

OS: Windows XP
Compiler: GCC 4.6.2
Libraries: MinGW

EDIT:
By trying to use `srand`, I discovered that this is the result from a seed of 1 (which I guess is made default).

Comment: +1 for short, complete example program. +1 for showing what the program produces. +1 for showing what you expect it to produce.

Comment: You're suggesting that the random number generator would need to be seeded before every call to rand?  That sounds more like a user generated number than a randomly generated number.

Comment: If all appearances of `rand` in a function gave the same result, it'll be not useful at all.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, That's the way I always learned how to use this exact function in the past: set the seed to something (eg. time(NULL)) before each call, otherwise the same result was produced.

Comment: @chris: I think you are misremembering your learning.  What you were probably told is something more like "you need to seed the random number generator before you start using it, otherwise you will get the same *sequence* of values every time"

Comment: FYI: http://c-faq.com/lib/srand.html

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Perhaps I was. It may have been a mixup with the fact that every time you run the program it gives the same result, rather than every function call. I do believe this is the case. Thanks for jogging my memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each call to `rand()` will always generate a different random number.

The seed actually determines the sequence of random numbers that's created. Using a different seed will get you another 3 random numbers, but you will always get those 3 numbers for a given seed.

If you want to have the same number multiple times just call `rand()` once and save it in a variable.

Comment: Different calls to rand() can return the same value.

Comment: This was indeed the case. I was thinking of it differing every call instead of every execution. Granted that indeed a certain seed could mathematically end up generating the same three numbers.

Comment: David you're absolutely right, I just figured it's rare enough that it wasn't worth mentioning for this. I should've said that it always is (pseudo)random, whether it's actually the same number or not.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `rand()` multiple times intentionally produces a <strike>different</strike> random number each time you call it.

Unless your program calls `srand()` with a different value for each run, the sequence will be the same for each run.

You could use `srand()` with the time to make the entire sequence different each time.  You can also call `srand()` with a known value to reset the sequence - useful for testing.

See the documentation for [rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/) and [srand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/).

Comment: rand() could return the same number 3 times in a row.

Comment: That was my problem. I have to give credit to ThomasG for being the first to post an answer explaining the mistake in my thought process though.